# Excel IF Statement To Extract Company Name From Text String

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am using this formula to extract a company name from a text string if the string begins with "GQR: Company Name":

```
=IFERROR(MID(LEFT(G2,FIND(" | ",G2)-1),FIND(": ",G2)+2,LEN(G2)),"")
```

TEXT STRING EXAMPLE: GQR: Company Name | Category | Address | Phone | Web URL

If the text string simply begins with "Company Name" I use this formula:

```
=LEFT(G2,FIND(" ",G2,1)-1)
```

TEXT STRING EXAMPLE: Company Name | Category | Address | Phone | Web URL

What would be the Excel formula I would use if I wanted to extract the Company Name whether the text string begins with "GQR: Company Name" or just "Company Name"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RIGHT and LEFT to identify the ":" then embed it into an IF formula:

```
=IF(RIGHT(LEFT(G2,4),1)=":",IFERROR(MID(LEFT(G2,FIND(" | ",G2)-1),FIND(": ",G2)+2,LEN(G2)),""), LEFT(G2,FIND("|",G2,1)-1))
```

You can use this formula with any three digit letter combination followed by a ":"
[image]

Comment: My pleasure David.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
IF(LEFT(G2,4) = "GQR:",MID(LEFT(G2,FIND(" | ",G2)-1),FIND(": ",G2)+2,LEN(G2)),LEFT(G2,FIND(" ",G2,1)-1))
```